# AngularJS Kendo Treeview not updating

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

Thanks to the answer from "Words Like Jared" at [Angularjs + kendo-ui treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386992/angularjs-kendo-ui-treeview), I got my treeview working and everything was fine. Until - someone wanted to update/filter the treeview based on checkboxes and the like. My problem is that the tree does not update to reflect the change in the datasource made in the controller.

Based on the jsfiddle in the answer mentioned above, I have created one to show my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/rajeshmathew/LwDs5/

```
if ($scope.showLimitedRecords) {                    
$scope.thingsOptions = {dataSource: $scope.things2}                    
} else {
$scope.thingsOptions = { dataSource: $scope.things1 };                                        
}
```

Checking the checkbox does not affect the tree.
I am a newbie to AngularJS and angular-kendo, and I am wondering if this kind of an update is even supposed to work. I might be going at this the wrong way. Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create the data source explicitly and then set the data using its API:

```
$scope.thingsOptions = {
    dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: $scope.things1
    })
}
$scope.toggleFlag = function () {
    if ($scope.showLimitedRecords) {
        $scope.thingsOptions.dataSource.data($scope.things2);
    } else {
        $scope.thingsOptions.dataSource.data($scope.things1);
    }
}
```

([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/LwDs5/13/))